# Separating dates by month in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I understand in rails that you can query data using the controller which is what I have been doing.

However say I have a list of dates and I want to visually display them under each month like so:

```
August:
14/08/2015
25/08/2015
September:
12/09/2015
19/09/2015
October:
3/10/2015
8/10/2015
November:
25/11/2015
5/11/2015
```

Now I could query each month through the controller but in my eyes this is very inefficient. As a result could you do something like this in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the results with Ruby's collection [group_by method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
@items_by_month = @items.group_by{|x| x.created_at.month}
```

It will result in a Hash with the following structure:

```
{
  # January
  1 => [item1, item2, ...],
  # February
  2 => [item3, item4, ...],
  # ... and so on
}
```

Then you can iterate over that Hash in your view.